# Alternative experiemental or evaluation methods for programming language construct (artefact)

Tags: evaluation, experiment-design, evaluation-criteria

I am writing my B.Sc. in Computer Science. I am currently writing my **methods**  chapter and adhering to the **IMRaD structure** (https://writingcenter.gmu.edu/writing-resources/imrad/writing-an-imrad-report).

I am designing and implementing an interpreted programming language. I do classify my implementation as an artifact, as is normally classified and described within the Information Science Design studies.

According to **Briony J. Oates**, *Researching Information Systems and Computing
Second Edition*:

> Having developed an IT artefact, it must be evaluated. There are many criteria for
> evaluating an IT artefact: functionality, completeness, consistency, accuracy,
> performance, reliability, usability, accessibility, aesthetics, entertainment,
> fit with organization, and so on. The criteria you use depend on the reason you
> developed the artefact in the first place---they will be related to your original
> research objectives. The evaluation can lead to conclusions about the design
> process as well as the design product, and may suggest that further modifications
> to either or both are needed.

**Artefact:**
An interpreted programming language that is inspired by Scheme, and aims to be closer with the nature of Mathematical Expressionism (Notations and Symbols) of expressing a equation, sigma or other notations and functionality to a problem of investigation.

According to this book: *Concepts of Programming Languages (10th Edition)*
by **Robert W. Sebesta**.

The **1.3 Language Evaluation Criteria** includes this table:
[image]

**Question(s):**

- Are there other methods for evaluating a programming language? (*I am aware that performance can be used as a metric, quantitative research*)

---

**N.B:** I have already posted here a different questions concerning methods section/chapter in a thesis, [Choice of design science method for artifact creation in Computer Science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194862/choice-of-design-science-method-for-artifact-creation-in-computer-science).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a new here but I wish to share a few things because I am a researcher in the same field, however, it is not easy to list all possible methods or requirements.

I have reviewed papers on programming language evaluation, I have a seen few other points that have been discussed (besides what you listed). I admit I am not 100% certain about all the names. Hopefully this answer would eventually be edited to become more complete and correct... but here is how I could come up with it:

### Language Cost

- How hard to create a compiler, i.e. your effort to build the compiler;
- How hard to generate the compiled output, i.e. the computer effort to run the compiler, if all compilation must start from scratch or can be incremental;
- How hard to optimise the output, i.e. how good is the non-optimised and how hard is to optimise;
- How hard to teach users, i.e. how different is that from what users are seasoned;
- How hard to code (possibly duplicate with simplicity);
- How hard to debug, i.e. how hard to run and follow the lines at runtime;
- How hard to test, i.e. how hard to write tests, to see the test outputs, to compare the expected to actual.

### Popularity

- Many publications often cite popularity ranks (e.g. https://spectrum.ieee.org/top-programming-languages-2022) for new languages, they use it as a motivation for "making it similar to this specific language that is popular".

### Portability

- How the language model is portable to many platforms. In other words: Even if it is meant to be interpreted, could it be compiled to machine code, what kinds, how well it works on each platform.
- How the language can be used by different tools. For example, text editors, version control, encoding requirements.

Besides, I have watched some presentations about how some simplicity and syntax characteristics often allow users to write bad code.
There are many non technical characteristics that makes a language to thrive even if it is not good. Example: good tools, availability.

I am not sure if I am welcome to dump a load of references here, but there are many works on language testing and evaluation. Some create programs to automate testing; others conduct experiments with programmers or their code; besides other references. Your question reminded me of these references:

- [Testing an optimising compiler by generating random lambda terms](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1982595.1982615) (Haskell compiler tests);
- [How (and why) developers use the dynamic features of programming languages: the case of Smalltalk](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10664-012-9203-2) (Smalltalk expressivity analysis);
- [The Eval That Men Do](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22655-7_4) (Javascript feature usage).

I also recommend searching related papers from [ACM POPL](https://dl.acm.org/conference/popl).

By the way, remember to check the specification documents for programming languages that are similar to yours! They often include motivation for each evaluation.

I hope this is useful, best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

One reason this is hard to answer is that we don't know what goals you had in designing a new language. Your evaluation of the outcome should be in line with those goals. Somewhere early in your paper/thesis you should describe those goals and then develop some testing methodology to see if they have been met.

Some such are harder than others. If your goal was to be faster than C then there are benchmarks you can use.

Safety is a bit harder and we keep failing at it, but it remains a goal. For that you can do a theoretical analysis to explain how the language and/or its implementation makes certain common attacks hard/impossible. But a formal system of letting others try to attack your code is required in serious systems, though unlikely for an undergrad thesis.

But expressiveness is much harder. Is Java or Python more expressive? Is Common Lisp or Haskell? How easy is it to say the sorts of things that normally need to be said in programs in the anticipated problem space. Some comparison syntax with similar languages might do for this.

Design the evaluation around the goals.

Comment: Hi Buffy, I described here too, you missed it: `An interpreted programming language that is inspired by Scheme, and aims to be closer with the nature of Mathematical Expressionism (Notations and Symbols) of expressing a equation, sigma or other notations and functionality to a problem of investigation.`

Comment: Then use that to compare your language with others in the same paradigm. Showing equivalent programs, making sure you have best practice coding for all.

Comment: Buffy, I listed the `Language Evaluation Criteria` above. But, besides this one and `Performance` metric (quantitative), what other potential methods exists?

Comment: I doubt that performance evaluations are going to get you anywhere in an interpreted language. That depends on the implementation. If your goals are expression of math stuff, just do that. People are willing to take a big performance hit for expressiveness. C vs Python, for example. The others like reliability are a lot to ask for in a new language, unless you have an extensive test suite.

Comment: FWIW, I know people using Haskell to express key ideas in category theory. If you can do that, especially generating commutative diagrams, they would love it.